# Проблема на уровне сервера при смене шаблона

Tags: шаблоны, joomla, php, дизайн, вёрстка

Работаю на переделке Joomla. Пытаюсь перевязать шаблон. При смене .tpl файла шапки (измения в body) любая страница возвращает пустой результат. В то же время тот же контент, интегрированый в требуемый шаб на уровне .html отображается нормально. error_reporting(1); на требуемой странице и аналог в .htaccess не помогли, ошибку не отображает. Вставляемый код - http://paste.pro/3334994
Как исправить?

Comment: Версию джумлы и шаблон в студию плз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С жумлой не работал, но насколько я знаю, *.tpl файлы - это компилированые шаблоны... (в Smarty точно). Так вот, компилированный шаблон отличается от обычного html файлика тем, что он не рендерится напрямую в браузер, а сначала компилируется. Также для файлов-шаблонов (базируюсь на Smarty) используется специальный синтаксис. Кусочки javascript кода в таких шаблонах нужно изолировать.

И снова пример на Smarty

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
  function isblank(field) {
    if (field.value == '')
      { return false; }
    else
      {
      document.loginform.submit();
      return true;
    }
  }
</script>
{/literal}
```

Попробуйте порыть в эту сторону...